Getting 'ImportError: Library not loaded: libodbc.2.dylib' when using pyodbc in Python
I've faced an error for quite a while regarding pyodbc import failure. I am trying to run a flask file that also utilize sqlalchemy and I think there's some error with the connection
mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/Users/.../Documents/GitHub/.../__init__.py", line 31, in create_app
    db.init_app(app)

and the error message ends with this
return __import__("pyodbc")
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: <5AF90214-4330-3EDE-BF4E-3591DA912A63> /Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/lib/libodbc.2.dylib/libodbc.2.dylib' (errno=20), '/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

I have tried several method like reinstalling and trying to put pyodbc extension in the right $PATH but it keeps giving the same error message

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install#installing-on-macosx
